# powerpoint preview in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using vscode to edit markdown files, and I have sometime links to powerpoint file such as `[presentation](powerpoint.ppt)`.
I can now `Ctrl+Click` to open the powerpoint file in VScode, but it shows nothing than `the file is not displayed in the editor because it is either a binary or use unsupported text encoding...`
I would like to be able to preview the pptx file directely in vscode, or find a simple way to open it in an external application.
Any suggestion?
thanks

Comment: The best solution I have now:
1. "Reveal in File Explorer" using Shortcut (Ctrl + Alt + R) --> 
2. "Enter" to open it with Powerpoint...   
So, 2 additional steps after trying to open the file in the editor. 
any better solution?

Comment: I tried to understand your issue here, but I think I might not be getting it correctly. If you have the link to an external ppt (say google deck) then I believe it should work just as fine as any other links. Do you have the address of the local PPT which is on your machine, and you are trying to access that from markdown?

Comment: I can't see any such extension to view it inside VSCode, but you could convert it to PDF first and use a PDF viewer extension.

Comment: Here is an Extension that I found. I did not test if it works. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yuenm18.ooxml-viewer

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't open those files directly in VSCode, however you can open them in another application by using an extension such as [Open in External App](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YuTengjing.open-in-external-app#:%7E:text=In%20VSCode%2C%20Right%2Dclicking%20is,Open%20in%20Multiple%20External%20Apps%20.) (you can find the extension via the extension search in vscode).

Once installed you can update your `settings.json` configuration :

```json
{ 
 // [...]
"openInExternalApp.openMapper": [
        {
            // represent file extension name
            "extensionName": "pptx",
            // the external applications to open the file which extension name is html
            "apps": [
                // openCommand can be shell command or the complete executable application path
                // title will be shown in the drop list if there are several apps
                {
                    "title": "powerpoint",
                    // This will vary depending on your OS, you can also use a PPT viewer of your chosing
                    // On Windows, could be Program Files (x86) and a different version of Office, but you get the idea
                    "openCommand": "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\powerpnt.exe"
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mac owners would change this line.
"openCommand": "/Applications/Microsoft powerpoint.app"